# 3D functions with SFCGAL in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, postgis-2.0, geos

I have this set up: `"POSTGIS="2.1.2 r12389" GEOS="3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER"` on PostgreSQL-9.3

I installed CGAL 4.4 and SFCGAL

```
~# sfcgal-config --version
1.0.4
```

I would like to use 3D functions (ST_Extrude... etc) in my exiting databases, is it possible? I can't find proper information about this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm as I recall there should be in an sfcgal output in your postgis_full_version() output.  Did you compile postgis with sfcgal support?  It's not enough to just have sfcgal installed.

I see you are right the instructions in docs don't tell you how to compile with sfcgal support.  I'll amend that.

What you need to add is in your postgis configure

```
./configure --with-sfcgal=path/to/sfcgal-config
```

I think if you have sfcgal in default location, then --with-sfcgal is sufficient.